# LINQtoSQL creates Partial Classes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

In a LINQ to SQL class you get the option to View Code of any entity you drag in the design surface. This creates a Partial Class.

Lets say we have an Employee Entity and I create a partial class Employee. What can I use that partial class for? Is it to add Employee methods such as DoWork()?

Do I need to declare any variables that are in the table? (In case of Employee: Name, Surname etc) If so, how do I make the connection between the data present in the Employee record to the class?

Comment: perhaps this article can help you as well as understand what you are looking to do http://codesamplez.com/database/linq-to-sql-c-sharp-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

partial class is used in EF in order to allow you to make changes and additions to entity classes in a file that is not auto generated. Changes in and auto-generated file might be overridden when updating db context. The use of your own files which extend the partials defined in the auto-generated files prevents that. this also allows you to add implementation to partial methods defined in that partial class, most typically event handlers.
using a partial class in the same name space is very much similar to work inside the other part of class it extends, and it simply allows you to write one class in more than one file. for more information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: In the MSDN page I see two Employee partial classes, each having a different method. Is this considered as a type of polymorphism?

Comment: no. they both describe the same type, exists in the same namespace and the same dll. there is only one class described here, the physical separation of files makes no real logical difference between using one file. polymorphism means in general that types of the same kind with different values and methods implementation can be accessed the same way, thus allowing the object in control to use them without knowing all their specific details, and there is non of that here